# How to check whether mail client application is installed on PC by java code?

Tags: java, swt, email-client

Is there any way to check availability of mail client application on PC only through java code?
Or Native method is the only way to check that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried to read from registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail. But there will be always some entry under that registry so it will not give me correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet in the standard library is the [`Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class. It has 2 `mail()` methods which launch the mail composing window of the user default mail client.

You can check if this is supported with the `Desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL)` call.

Example:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (d.isSupported(Desktop.Action.MAIL))
        d.mail(new URI("mailto:somebody@somehost.com?subject=test"));
}
```

Comment: I can not use this solution as i am working with SWT.

Comment: This is part of the standard Java library and even if you use SWT for your GUI, this works. The `Desktop` class does not create or use any Java GUI - it opens the mail client of the Operating System.

Comment: I am working with JDK1.5 and Desktop class is introduce in JDK1.6. Hence, I can not use it. Is there any other solution?